# Dynamically created FireMonkey TPopupMenu doesn't Pop Up

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Start a new Multi-Device application and place a button on it. Declare a member variable in the form `POP: TPopupMenu`. Double-click the button and insert the following code in the event:

```
var
  MI    : TMenuItem;
  I     : Cardinal;
begin
  FreeAndNIL(POP); // POP is a member variable of the form
  POP:=TPopupMenu.Create(Self);
  FOR I:=1 TO 10 DO BEGIN
    MI:=TMenuItem.Create(POP);
    MI.Text:=IntToStr(I);
    MI.OnClick:=Button1Click;
    POP.AddObject(MI)
  END;
  POP.Popup(100,100)
end;
```

(I know that assigning Button1Click to OnClick will lead to recursive calls, but I have included it to preempt suggestions that there are no events associated with the `TMenuItem`).

It should pop up a menu when you click the button, but it doesn't (actually, it kinda does - it pops up a 0-pixel width popup menu, which you can verify in that the button doesn't "glow" when you move the mouse over it, until you have clicked somewhere to "close" this (unseen) popup menu).

I can see (if I trace into `POP.PopUp`) that it transfers the `TMenuItem`s into a new popup menu type, and starts calculating the size of the popup. But when it iterates over the items, it skips the part that handles the width of the menu items' texts (there's no "TextObject", ie. it's NIL).

If I do the similar code in VCL it works fine, so what is different in FMX that makes this not work? Do I need to "commit" the `TPopupMenu` changes or what?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to assign `POP.Parent`

Comment: I don't need to do that in VCL... TPopupMenu in VCL doesn't even have a Parent property... What should I assign Parent to? It's not a right-click menu - it's a manually created popup menu in response to some unrelated event. I'll try to assign a value to Parent tomorrow...

Comment: What you do or don't in VCL might be rather pointless when you work in FMX. Assign something visible (of course), like e.g. current form. The coords are anyway screen coords.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Setting `POP.Parent` to my form works - thank you. If you could flesh out your comment into a full-blown answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `FMX` framework, a `TPopupMenu` needs to have either the `PopupComponent` or the `Parent` property set, to become visible when called. Since you want to create a popup menu that is not tied to any specific control as a that controls popup menu (made visible with a right-click), you must assign its `Parent` property:

```
POP.Parent := Self; // The form in your example
```

Note that the coordinates passed to `POP.Popup()` are screen coordinates despite the parent setting.

Comment: I did the same, but instead of indicating "Self" I put the Layout1 object which is covering the whole surface of the FORM (align=Content). No change.